# Как правильно уменьшительно-ласкательное от имени Ульяна?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно : Улечка или Уличка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: Улечка.

В ласкательных мужских и женских именах используется суффикс ечк. Напр.:  Ванечка, Олечка, Анечка.

Comment: Попробовали бы Аничку Ахматову обозвать Анечкой - в гробу бы перевернулась... )))

Comment: Галина, суффикс "ичк"  уже устарел.

Comment: Я знаю, Сержинька! Но до сих пор активно ими пользуюсь. )))